# Reading & Writing Grayscale TIF files in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tiff

I'm trying to extract a (very) large number of subimages from a large grayscale TIF file and save each image as a GIF, PNG, or even another TIF  using MATLAB. I'm able to display the individual images using `imshow(sub(:,:,1),cmap)` but when I try to write the data to an image file, the generated files are just white squares 101x101 px. Using the `cmap` argument in `imwrite` produces the same result, as does changing the image format (I've tried with PNG, TIF, GIF, and JPG with no luck). The file `a.tif` is 16 bit according to the property menu in Windows Explorer. Any help is appreciated. I'm really at wit's end with this.

```
    % Import coordinates array and correct for multiplication by 10
    datafile = 'data.xlsx';
    coords = xlsread(datafile,1,'G2:H13057');
    x = coords(:,1) ./ 10;
    y = coords(:,2) ./ 10;
    r = 50;
    [img, cmap] = imread('a.tif'); % import the image

    s = 2*r+1; % scalar of size of each submatrix in the array (sise of image)
    sub = zeros(s,s,num); % create 3D matrix/array of matrices. Each submatrix corresponds to 50 px box around each point
    i = 1:4;
    subrgb = zeros(s,s,num);

    for i=1:4
       sub(:,:,i) = img((y(i)-r):(y(i)+r),(x(i)-r):(x(i)+r));
       filename = 'dot_%d.png';
       filename = sprintf(filename,i);
       imwrite(sub(:,:,i),filename,'png');
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
sub = zeros(s,s,num);
```

to:

```
sub = zeros(s,s,num,class(img));
```

I assume that the problem is that sub is of type double.

Good luck

Comment: I think the issue is with 'cmap'. It's returning a blank array regardless of the type I cast img or sub as. Using your suggestion continues to return a blank image. Do you have any suggestions to deal with that?

Comment: If you don't use cmap, just fo: img = imread('a.tif'); is img blank? try imshow(img,[])

Comment: Using imread and imshow without a cmap just gives a blank image. With imshow(img,[]), Matlab gives the correct image but imwrite writes either a black or white blank image in the output file.

Comment: Alrighty, after further Googling, I fount that using the function im2double(img) made everything work.